# Unable to Debug because getting an error message --'There is no source code available for the current location'

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

Whenever I click on the ‘No’ in the message box window then the flow enter to the btnMsgBtn_click method. 
If we continue to debug the code then after the end of the method it will encounter the error message. 
After clicking on the OK button of the error message if we press F10 or F11 it will encounter the same error. So after this point we are unable to debug further.

Can you please assist so that I am able to Debug the code and get over the error message?

Comment: in the debug view you should see your stack trace at that breakpoint, just click (or double-click) on the first entry with YOUR code. there should be some lines with trace from windows libraries, for which there is of course no source code available

Comment: Thanks @Marian Theisen. Looking at the stack trace during debug mode, I didnt find any trace from Windows libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the executable and the debug information in the pdb is out of sync, or sometimes the debugger loses the connection to the pdb server engine.  I would suggest restarting Visual Studio and then doing a complete rebuild of the solution.